Insulating living space inside a shop
I have a shop that is dried in, but not insulated. I have built a living space inside this building. The "exterior" walls do not have to protect from water, but I assume I need a vapor barrier and insulation. I live in the houston area. There is an air conditioner and electric heaters for winter.
I was thinking Rockwall insulation for sound deadening. What kind of vapor barrier do I need?

The problem is air not vapor
The term "vapor barrier" is a misnomer -- what most people are really after in an exterior assembly is an air barrier as the amount of water that gets in through vapor diffusion is insignificant compared to the amount of water that gets in via being carried by leaking air.
In a dried-in shop space, though, water vapor in the leaking air is less of an issue, but air leaks can carry lots of other nasty things, like smoke and fumes.  So, this wall still needs to have an air barrier function as a practical matter.  The good news is that the already-necessary drywall on the shop side can serve as that air barrier provided it's taped properly and not penetrated for things like outlet boxes.
So, overall, I'd use a 2x4 wall assembly with rockwool batts and fire-taped 5/8" Type X drywall on both sides.  This will get you the 1 hour fire rating required by IBC 420.2 & 708.3 for something separating a dwelling unit from another occupancy (your shop) in the same building.  The doors between the shop and the living space will need to be 45-minute or better fire rated doors (not hard to find if you're looking at commercial hollow metal), and you'll need to use firecaulk for all through-penetrations and firestopping putty pads for any junction or outlet boxes on the inside (house side) of this wall.
That, plus keeping all the shop-side electrical on the surface of the wall, will allow it to effectively protect your new home from all the myriad things that could go wrong in your shop.
